# Spark RDD tuple transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to transform an RDD of tuple of Strings of this format :

`(("abc","xyz","123","2016-02-26T18:31:56"),"15")` TO

```
(("abc","xyz","123"),"2016-02-26T18:31:56","15")
```

Basically seperating out the timestamp string as a seperate tuple element. I tried following but it's still not clean and correct.

```
val result = rdd.map(r => (r._1.toString.split(",").toVector.dropRight(1).toString, r._1.toString.split(",").toList.last.toString, r._2))
```

However, it results in

```
(Vector(("abc", "xyz", "123"),"2016-02-26T18:31:56"),"15")
```

The expected output I'm looking for is

```
(("abc", "xyz", "123"),"2016-02-26T18:31:56","15")
```

This way I can access the elements using `r._1`, `r._2` (the timestamp string) and `r._3` in a seperate map operation.

Any hints/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector.toString` will include the String 'Vector' in its result. Instead, use `Vector.mkString(",")`.

Example:

```
scala> val xs = Vector(1,2,3)
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> xs.toString
res25: String = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> xs.mkString
res26: String = 123

scala> xs.mkString(",")
res27: String = 1,2,3
```

However, if you want to be able to access `(abc,xyz,123)` as a Tuple and not as a string, you could also do the following:

```
val res = rdd.map{
  case ((a:String,b:String,c:String,ts:String),d:String) => ((a,b,c),ts,d)
}
```